# How to rotate an object to point at another point in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to get a CCSprite to rotate and point at any point on the screen on which a user taps. My tap detection is working. This is my rotation code:

```
double delX = touchPoint.x - _hero.position.x;
double delY = touchPoint.y - _hero.position.y;
int theta = atan(delY/delX);

theta = theta * (180/M_PI); // conversion to degrees
if (theta < 0)
{
    theta = abs(theta) + 90;
}
theta = abs(theta);

theta += 180;


bullet.rotation = -1*theta; // to turn right instead of left, the -1
```

The bullet is at _hero.position, and touchPoint is the point at which the user tapped. Any ideas?

EDIT: Thank you, flowmachine1! except for some reason it was backwards, so I just added this code to your answer:

```
if (angle<90)
{
    angle = abs(90-angle) + 90;
}else if (angle >90)
{
    angle = 90 - abs(90-angle);
}
```

and then it worked! Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you run this code and what do you expect it to happen? It appears that your code should work, probably it would be better to use atan2 function as it will handle all angles not just (-90, 90) range.

Comment: when i run it, it points to a general one side of the screen or another, & isn't very accurate. also, when i tap the bottom left, it points toward the bottom right

Comment: So try to replace atan with atan2 and remove the code that is recalculating angles (apart from conversion to degrees).

Comment: it's begun pointing mostly towards 0, and randomly in other directions. i'm working for iphone dev in obj c if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
pos1 = touchPosition;
pos2 = spritePosition;

double angle = atan2(pos1.y - pos2.y, pos1.x - pos2.x) * 180 / M_PI;

sprite.rotation = angle;
```